# How to inject services in a controller inside a reusable Razor Class Library

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I am using a Razor Class Library for making a reusable complex View (which includes its controller and several View Components) that can be used across several ASP.NET Core MVC projects. The problem is that the controller use dependency injection (a custom service called "GatewayProxy" and string localization). What is the correct way to inject services into a controller inside a RCL?

Here is the structure of my RCL:

[image]

Here is the exception:

[image]

Comment: did you register the dependencies with the service collection on startup?

Comment: Should I make a Startup.cs in the RCL project or in the ASP.NET MVC project?

Comment: The main MVC project. It should already have one. Register dependencies there

Comment: @Nkosi It worked. I managed to create a very promising reusable RCL. The only problem left is the lack of support for static files like javascript. Do you know a good way to include them in my RCL?

Comment: @RenatoSanhueza: That should really be separate question, but generally, you have to add them as embedded resources (`<ItemGroup><EmbeddedResource Include="wwwroot\**\*" /></ItemGroup>`). Then, you'll need to add the embedded file provider in your actual web application that's utilizing this RCL to get them. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.1#manifestembeddedfileprovider

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You mentioned how you fixed this by adding the dependencies to Startup.cs of your main project. But consider that any consumer of this reuseable library may not remember (or know) what dependencies are needed for your library.

Something you can do to solve this is to create an extension off of `IServiceCollection` in your Rcl that does the dependency registration.

```
public static void AddMyRclServices(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection, IConfiguration config)
{
    serviceCollection.AddTransient<IRclService1, RclService1>();
    serviceCollection.AddScoped<IRclService2, RclService2>();
}
```

Then in `Startup.cs` for your MVC project call the extension

```
using Rcl.Extensions

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMyRclServices(config);
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best approach, but not perfect, because the consumer of the RCL still has to know to invoke services.AddMyRclServices(config).  I wish there was a Startup.cs for the RCL.

Comment: @Tolga did u fint the startup.cs in 2.2 RCL yet >

Comment: Where/How do you include this in the RCL and the component?

Comment: Create a public static class somewhere in your RCL

Answer (score 1):

You can inject from load assemblies. 
my code

ISturtupInitializers.cs

```
public interface ISturtupInitializers {
    void Compose(IServiceCollection serviceCollection);
}
```

TypeLoader.cs

```
public static readonly Lazy<HashSet<Assembly>> AllAssemblies = new Lazy<HashSet<Assembly>>(() => {
    var bin_folder = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetFileInfo().Directory.FullName;
    var bin_assembly_files = Directory.GetFiles(bin_folder, "*.dll", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Where(x => !SystemAssemblies.Any(xs => x.IndexOf(xs, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)).ToList();
    var assemblies = new HashSet<Assembly>();
    foreach (var a in bin_assembly_files)
    {
        try {
            var assName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(a);
            var ass = Assembly.Load(assName);
            assemblies.Add(ass);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            //ignore
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            //ignore
        } catch (BadImageFormatException e) {
            //ignore
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return assemblies;
});

public static string[] SystemAssemblies = new[] {
    "Microsoft.",
    "System.",
    "Newtonsoft."
};
public static FileInfo GetFileInfo(this Assembly assembly)
{
    var uri = new Uri(assembly.CodeBase);
    var path = uri.LocalPath;
    return new FileInfo(path);
}
```

Composer.cs

```
public class Composer {
    private static readonly Lazy<HashSet<Type>> _sturtup_initializers = new Lazy<HashSet<Type>>(() => {
        var aseemblies = TypeLoader.AllAssemblies.Value.SelectMany(x=>GetAllTypesInAssembly(x, typeof(ISturtupInitializers)));
        var result = new HashSet<Type>();
        foreach (var item in aseemblies) {
            result.Add(item);
        }

        return result;
    });

    public static void Compose(IServiceCollection services) {
        var composers = _sturtup_initializers.Value;

        foreach (var compose in composers) {
            public static void Compose(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration) {
        var composers = _sturtup_initializers.Value;

        var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        foreach (var compose in composers) {
            ((IStartupInitializers) ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(provider, compose)).Compose(services, configuration);
        }
    }
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Type> GetAllTypesInAssembly(Assembly assembly, Type implementInterface) {
        var types = assembly.GetTypes();
        return types.Where(x => x.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i == implementInterface));
    }
}
```

MyStartup.cs

```
public class ServiceCollectionExtensions : ISturtupInitializers
{
    public void Compose(IServiceCollection serviceCollection) {
        /** YOUR CODE **/
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    /** YOUR CODE **/
    Composer.Compose(services);
}
```